# Wrapping a div around the document body contents

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I am trying to dynamically wrap the contents of a document's body tag in a DIV. So far, I have used the following code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="wrap">' + document.body.innerHTML + '</div>';
```

This works, but has the unwanted side effect that other scripts on the same page stop working (I assume because changing innerHTML renders any object references they may have held useless).

What would be the best/most efficient way to achieve this and keep the references intact, using pure JavaScript, or the Prototype framework?

Comment: just curious, why would you wan't to do this? I'm pretty sure this wouldn't validate (if it weren't done dynamically with JS)

Comment: I think the way I phrased the title might be misleading - it's the contents of the document body I was trying to wrap, not the body tag itself :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "wrap";

// Move the body's children into this wrapper
while (document.body.firstChild)
{
    div.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
}

// Append the wrapper to the body
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: The problem is, that all attached JavaScript events get lost when you reassign html-content this way.

Comment: Or at least the ones that are assigned within the code (I guess the onlick-handlers still remain intact).

Comment: Strange. By doing it this way, most DOM objects are completely unaffected, and even the body's children only have their position altered. Attached events should be completely unchanged. Not like if you did something like `document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='wrap'>" + document.body.innerHTML + "</div>";` ! :)

Comment: @AnthonyMills If events are still attached then it's because the DOM objects aren't re-written unlike when doing `.innerHTML`

Comment: @Benjamin yes, I thought that was clear in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this? (untested)

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
newDiv.setAttribute('id','wrap');
var bodyChildren = document.body.childNodes;
for(var i=0;i<bodyChildren.length;i++){
  newDiv.append(bodyChildren[i]);
}
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Not sure about prototype, but in jQuery you can do this

```
$('body').wrap('<div id="wrap"></div>');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say, only difference I would have mentioned, use the Prototype DOM Builder: http://prototypejs.org/2007/5/12/dom-builder

Comment: Thank you! (There's a wrap method in prototype that I experimented with, but I only managed to wrap the div around the outside of the body, not the inside).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var body = document.body;
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'wrapper';

div.innerHTML = body.innerHTML;
body.innerHTML = div.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').wrap('<div class=body></div>');
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').replaceWith(function() {return this.innerHTML});
$('#iframe').contents().find('.body').wrap('<body></body>');
```

this lines are going to wrap a div inside body element tag. First, it will wrap the body tag, then remove the body tag and append its all contents to the body div and the 3rd line will wrap this div again with the body tag.

Comment: -1 for assuming the wrong framework and not answering the question (using `innerHTML` does not preserve event handlers).

Comment: @clockworkgeek: i think i have given up the right answer, you need put these lines right on $(window).load function before binding any events   to the elements.
And $('#iframe') is just for an example, you could have use any other id of element

Comment: @Nadeem - The correct answer would simply be `$('body').wrapInner('<div id="wrap"/>');`...but clock is correct, that still *assumes* the asker is using jQuery, and that's a bad assumption to make.